# Net 6 showing 500.19 error reading the wrong web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I deployed a brand new site on IIS. It is in .Net 6. I am getting a 500.19 error that it cannot read the configuration file due to insufficient permissions.

```
\\?\D\Sites\SiteDirectory\wwwroot\web.config
```

The problem is this web.config file that it is pointing to is not the one for my website. It is looking for a web.config in the wwwroot directory for some reason. As a matter of fact there is no web.config that even exists at that location.

The correct web.config file exists in
D:\Sites\SiteDirectory\wwwroot\SiteName\web.config

Why is IIS looking at wwwroot? How can I fix this behavior? My other .Net Framework 4.7 sites work fine without this web.config at the root directory.

Comment: What kind of drive is your D drive? A mapped drive?

Comment: D drive is where all of the website are. Its a logical drive on the server.

Comment: Try to use failed request tracking to view detailed error information about 500.19.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by installing this component:

Windows Hosting Bundle

"https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Solved my problem. It's funny that the runtime and the hosting bundle are different and need to be installed separately. Very confusing and misleading.